# Chromium Embed in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, chromium, qwebelement

I am making an application which needs to have a browser inside an application. I was previously going with JavaFX and its WebView.

But since I prefer Chromium, and since Qt can natively run on Linux without installing anything else, I am leaning to use Qt, since [it changed its default web engine to Chromium last year](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/09/12/introducing-the-qt-webengine/).

Anyways there isn't good documentation on how to use it. So it would be great help if anyone  who might have experience with it can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This will be available no earlier than Qt 5.3, so you need to wait a bit. Qt 5.2 still uses webkit.